# replacing all consecutive duplicates from the string with allowed no of occurrences

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I need to write a method that takes a String as a parameter and returns a new String obtained by replacing every instance of repeated adjacent letters with a `'n'` instances of that string.

For example, if `"aaabcccd"` as an input String and `n =2`, it returns `"aabccd"`. I already tried the following code, but not getting expected output

```
String in = "aaadbbb";
char[] s = in.toCharArray();
int len = s.length;

int n = 2;
StringBuffer new_s = new StringBuffer("");
int count = 1;
char prev='\0';

for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    if (s[i] == s[i + 1]) {
       if(count <= n){
            new_s.append(s[i]);
           count++;
        }else{
         count=1;
       }
    } else {
        new_s.append(s[i]);
    }
}
   
System.out.println(new_s);
```

output-`aaadb`
expected-`aadbb`

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your code?

Answer (score 3):

Can be done with regexp magic using backreferences.

```
String in = "aaaaddbbbbc";
int n = 2;
String pattern = String.format("(([a-z])\\2{%d})\\2+", n - 1);
System.out.println(in.replaceAll(pattern, "$1"));
```

Outputs:

> aaddbbc

Explanation:
The number inside `{}` is `n-1`.

`([a-z])` is a capture group, matching any single lowercase letter from a to z. Since it's a second group of parentheses in the expression, it can be referenced as `2`.

`(([a-z])\\2{n})` means "match n+1 repetitions of same letter". It makes up a first capture group, and we'll use that as replacement

`\\2+` matches all the extra repetitions of the same letter. They are discarded after replacement.

Comment: very interesting approach. Can you adjust it for variable lengths?

Comment: Sure. Updated the answer to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track.  I'm not sure whether this is an assignment, so I don't want to just straight up give you an answer, but here are some hints that might help:

1. You're already iterating over the string.  This is great! However, I think you want to compare the *current* character with the *previous* character, and not the next character.
2. You don't need to convert your input to a char array to iterate over it, just use `charAt(idx)`
3. You never seem to use prev, but I think you had the right idea in mind when you declared it!
4. Break your problem into two parts: When to update count and when to append a character.  You can tackle both in your for loop, but instead of trying to do both things in the same if statements, break it up into multiple ifs.

The 3 things to do are:

- Update Prev Value
- Update Count
- Update new String

Getting the right order for these and the exact implementation I'll leave to you (again, because I'm not sure if this is an assignment or not)

Update: Since others posted, here is my solution (with single for loop):

```java
private String replaceConsecutiveDuplicates(String input, int n) {
    if (input == null || input.length() < n) return input;
    if (n == 0) return "";

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    int count = 1;
    char prev = input.charAt(0);
    sb.append(prev);

    char current;
    for( int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++) {
        current = input.charAt(i);
        if (prev == current) {
            if (++count > n) continue;
        } else {
            count = 1; 
        }
        prev = current;
        sb.append(current);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: thanks, Alex,
But just want to ask you, is only one for loop is sufficient?

Comment: Yes, you can do this in a single for loop.  The "3 things to do" all happen within it :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with the single loop solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static String test(String input, int repetitions) {
    String flag = "";
    String replacement = "";
    String output = input;
    ArrayList<Character> prevLetters = new ArrayList<Character>();

    for(int x = 0; x < input.length(); x++) {
        if(!prevLetters.contains(input.charAt(x))) {
            for(int y = 0; y <= repetitions ; y++) {
                flag += String.valueOf(input.charAt(x));
            }
            if(input.contains(flag)) {
                replacement = flag.substring(0, flag.length()-1);
                while(output.contains(flag)){
                    output = output.replace(flag, replacement);
                }
            }
            flag = "";
            prevLetters.add(input.charAt(x));
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

That is my solution, which follows a similar idea as yours. Rather than comparing each character value however, I thought it would be easier to simply check for a break in the rules (character appearing n+1 times in a row) and 'fix' it.

If you are interested in using your method, one potential issue that I noticed is that you aren't assigning count to 1 in your last else. You also won't have the chance to add the final character due to you only adding the character at index 'i' when the duration for the loop is len - 1.

Answer (score 1):

To add one more alternative:

```
    String in = "aaadbbbjjkllllllopp";
    int n = 2;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char temp = in.charAt(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < in.length()-1;){   // note that the incrementation of i is moved to the while loop
        temp = in.charAt(i);            // save current char in temp variable
        int count = 0;
        while (i < in.length() && in.charAt(i) == temp) {   ///iterate as long as you find same chars or hit the end of the string
            i++;
            count++;
        }
        if (count > n){   // if and only if count is greater than max allowed set it to max allowed
            count = n;
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < count; j++){   // append count chars
            sb.append(temp);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this solution. You should take care of the last char in your input string, as you iterate only to the last but one.

```
private void replaceConsecutiveDuplicates() {
    String input = "aaadbbb";
    int n = 2;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int count = 1;
    char current;

    for( int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i){
        current = input.charAt(i);
        if (i + 1 < input.length() && current == input.charAt(i + 1)) {
            ++count;
        } else if (count > 1) {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                sb.append(current);
            }
            count = 1;
        }
        else {
            sb.append(current);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```